# Datamapper - Is id contained in result set

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, datamapper, ruby-datamapper

What's the most elegant way of knowing if the current selection ID is already part of the Datamapper results, without iterating through all of the results and building an Array?

```
    @saved_item = Array.new
    current_user.items.all.each do |item|
            @saved_items.push(item.id)
    end

    if (@saved_items.include?(selection.id))
            true
    else
            false
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

`current_user.items.detect { |i| i.id == selection.id }` will return a boolean (true/false) indicating whether the selection id is included in the current_user.items collection.

Comment: hmm I'm pretty sure #detect will return an item with the given id. I'd suggest using #any? instead like this:

current_user.items.all.any? { |i| i.id == selection.id }

Comment: solnic is right: `#detect` returns the first instance for which the given block returns true, or nil if none of the instances in the collection do.

Answer (score 0):

> current_user.items.delete(selection.id)

this also you can use which will return the selection id from the array if presence else would return nil.